# HttpWebRequest possibly slowing website

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

Using Visual studio 2012, C#.net 4.5 , SQL Server 2008, Feefo, Nopcommerce

Hey guys I have Recently implemented a new review service into a current site we have.

When the change went live the first day all worked fine.

Since then though the sending of sales to Feefo hasnt been working, There  are no logs either of anything going wrong.

In the OrderProcessingService.cs in Nop Commerce's Service, i call a HttpWebrequest when an order has been confirmed as completed. Here is the code.

```
var email = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(order.Customer.Email.ToString());
var name = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(order.Customer.GetFullName().ToString());
var description = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(productVariant.ProductVariant.Product.MetaDescription != null ? productVariant.ProductVariant.Product.MetaDescription.ToString() : "product");
var orderRef = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(order.Id.ToString());
var productLink = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Format("myurl/p/{0}/{1}", productVariant.ProductVariant.ProductId, productVariant.ProductVariant.Name.Replace(" ", "-")));

string itemRef = "";

try
{
    itemRef = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(productVariant.ProductVariant.ProductId.ToString());
}
catch
{
    itemRef = "0";
} 

var url = string.Format("feefo Url",
login, password,email,name,description,orderRef,productLink,itemRef);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.Proxy = null;

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    if (response.StatusDescription == "OK")
    {
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        if(stream != null)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see its a simple webrequest that is processed on an order, and all product variants are sent to feefo.

Now:

1. this hasnt been happening all week since the 15th (day of the
   implementation)
2. the site has been grinding to a halt recently.

The stream and reader in the the var content is there for debugging.

Im wondering does the code redflag anything to you that could relate to the process of website?
Also note i have run some SQL statements to see if there is any deadlocks or large escalations, so far seems fine, Logs have also been fine just the usual logging of Bots.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: also note that this code is in a method that is called and wrapped in A try catch

UPDATE: well forget about the "not sending", thats because i was just told my code was rolled back last week

Comment: In order to give you a better answer, can you indicate the exact point where you have added that code?

Comment: Its part of the "OrderProcessingService.cs" found in Nop.Services.Orders  in the orderprocessing method, there is an "if" statement that checks if an order is "confirmed", if so it trys to call the method, which is where my code is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A call to another web site while processing the order can degrade performance, as you are calling to a site that you do not control. You don't know how much time it is going to take. Furthermore, the GetResponse method can throw an exception, if you don't log anything in your outer try/catch block then you won't be able to know what's happening.

The best way to perform such a task is to implement something like the "Send Emails" scheduled task, and send data when you can afford to wait for the remote service. It is easy if you try. It is more resilient and easier to maintain if you upgrade the nopCommerce code base.

This is how I do similar things:

1. Avoid modifying the OrderProcessingService: Create a custom service or plugin that consumes the `OrderPlacedEvent` or the `OrderPaidEvent` (just implement the `IConsumer<OrderPaidEvent>` or `IConsumer<OrderPlacedEvent>` interface).
2. Do not call to a third party service directly while processing the request if you don't need the response at that moment. It will only delay your process. At the service created in step 1, store data and send it to Feefo later. You can store data to database or use an static collection if you don't mind losing pending data when restarting the site (that could be ok for statistical data for instance).
3. Best way to implement point #2 is to add a new scheduled task implementing `ITask` (remember to add a record to the ScheduleTask table). Just recover the stored data do your processing.
4. Add some logging. It is easy, just get an `ILogger` instance and call `Insert`.

Comment: Great advice, there.  Yes the try catch i have calling the method is catching any arrors and logging them, so far though not a single error has been thrown.

Ill take a look at further seperation from the order-processing service as i must agree it sounds to be the likely culprit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are making a blocking synchronous call to other websites, which will definitely slow down your site in between the request-response process. What *Marco* has suggested is valid, try to do it in an ITask. Or you can use an asynchronous web request to potentially remove the block, if you need things done immediately instead of scheduled. :)